# Disqus SSO and Avatar

Tags: single-sign-on, disqus, avatar

I am using the disqus widget on a page to enable users to comment. I am able to SSO the user and also set a profile link. I was also able to pass avatar link and have users avatar appear on the disqus widget. But today I am not sure what happened. Any new users who has a avatar and trying to post a comment, the disqus does not show the user avatar any more. It still SSO's the user though. I used the Disqus SSO Console to read the encoded string and I can see the working avatar link too.

Debug SSO Payload:

```
{
"username":"***",
"id":"******",
"avatar":"107.21.235.146/application/themes/ifrs/images/ico-mypphoto.jpg",
"email":"****@google.com"
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Can someone tell how to debug this issue?

Thanks,
Rag

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the full path to the URL, including the protocol. So it should look like this:

```
"avatar": "http://107.21.235.146/application/themes/ifrs/images/ico-mypphoto.jpg",
```